# DataTable does not react to the logic I implemented

Tags: c#, datatable

I've been trying to implement a logic on a DataTable to find and eliminate orphan rows. If the number in Cell 26 of a record is not reflected in any of Cell 21 of the table, then the row is considered an Orphan and should be eliminated. I do not understand why my code is not working:

```
DataTable t = Session["SessionData"] as DataTable;
DataRow[] rows = t.Select();
int occurance;
int n = 0;
string Orphan = "";
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    if(rows[i][26].ToString() != "0")//An additional condition that shouldn't affect
    {
        occurance = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < rows.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j != i)
            {
                n = i;
                if (rows[i][26].ToString() == rows[j][21].ToString())
                {
                    occurance = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(occurance == 0)
        {
            Orphan = rows[n][26].ToString();
            t.Rows[n].Delete();
            t.AcceptChanges();
            Session["SessionData"] = t;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Orphan))
{
    ClearOrphans(null, null);
}
```

In order to avoid incoherences in the DataTable indexes I only do one delete operation, save the data to the session parameter and restart that same routine all over again until no orphan row is detected. The code does not even seem to enter the `if(occurance == 0)` condition

Comment: Time to use  the debugger perhaps?

Comment: Drop a breakpoint and step through your code and see what is happening. You can inspect the values of each variable in each loop iteration. This will reveal where the problem is occurring.

Comment: What is the type of the fields 21 and 26? You are converting them to string, but i wonder what they are actually.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the comment. It doesn't throw any error, though. It just doesn't do what I expect. Would the debugger help me in such a case? I will google to see how this could be achieved. I only used the debugging tag in the declaration of the asp webpages so far.

Comment: @Tim, those are integer field and you are right that the conversion there is unnecessary... but harmless and more robust.

Comment: Whatever editor you're using to write your c# code may have a debugger built in. [Visual Studio does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022). Just search for "how to debug using _whatever-editor_"

Comment: I can't make the IIS Express deliver to localhost... it gives me a connection error and none of the hints worked for me. I am working in a virtual desktop environment and can't create the necessary certificates. So no debugging for me at that stage! I will ask to get Visual Studio on my local session. Thanks anyway for the hints!

Comment: I just want to also point out that you say you want Cell 26 / Cell 21, but you're actually getting something different since your `i` and `j` indexes start at 0. "Cell 1" would be `[0][0]`. Also, if you don't have a debugger, the "old school" way to debug would be to hand write the values your code produces through a few loops. The problem with hand writing is that you can make mistakes and assume a value is something when in fact it's not actually that value. But it can be a way to catch problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to fix this "spaghetti-code", maybe an easier LINQ solution helps:

```
var cell21Values = t.AsEnumerable().Select((r,ix) => (Index:ix, Value:r.Field<int>(21)));
var cell26Values = t.AsEnumerable().Select((r,ix) => (Index:ix, Value:r.Field<int>(26), Row:r));
var orphaned = cell26Values
    .Where(x26 => !cell21Values.Any(x21 => x21.Index != x26.Index && x21.Value == x26.Value))
    .ToList();
orphaned.ForEach(x26 => x26.Row.Delete());
t.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: I am a bit offended by you calling the code "spaghetti-code"... looping through 2 tables looks that way, but I will definetly try to see what the LINQ expression could do in this case. Thank you!